# 404 page after okta authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, okta

I have created a sample spring-boot with okta application by following the instruction from https://dzone.com/articles/build-an-oauth-20-authorization-server-with-spring

When I run the application in my local network ( without any network proxy) it works fine.

It redirected to my okta login page and on successful login it shown my home page also.

But when I ran the same build in my test environment ( with network proxy) it is showing 404 page instead of my home page.

It redirected to my okta login page and on successful login it redirected to my home page but instead of home page it is showing 404 page

NOTE: the same build is working fine in my local but when I ran in test environment with proxy settings it is showing 404 page instead of home page on successful login of okta.

Here is my code base:
**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8080

okta:
  oauth2:
    issuer: https://dev-XXXXXX.okta.com/oauth2/default
    client-id: XXXXXX               
    client-secret: XXXXXX
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

**home.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<h1> secured home page </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.baji.okta</groupId>
    <artifactId>OktaOAuthClient</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>OktaOAuthClient</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

After the successful login, Okta redirects request back to the post login re-direct url. Seems like in your case, you have configured localhost as your re-direct url, but in test env, that is not the case.